# postfix limit sending rate PER MX domain?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, email-bounces

I know postfix can limit concurrent connections to recipient "domains", but I am sending emails to websites from different domains that may use the same email service (Google, Outlook, etc.) for the MX domains. Is there a way to limit the sending rate by the *MX* domain as opposed to the domain of the email address?